# Laravel 5.4 SQL Query Nested Where/OrWhere

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have these tables

**Loans Table**
| coop_id | loan_id | loan_availability |

**Loan Seasons Table**
| coop_id | loan_id | loan_season_start | loan_season_end |

And I'm trying to get the details of each loan in one array whether their availability is **Always** or **Seasonal**. If it is marked as seasonal, it has a data in the loan seasons table.

This is my query

```
$loanlist = DB::table('loans')
        ->join('loan_seasons', 'loan_seasons.loan_id', 'loans.loan_id')
        ->where('loans.coop_id', $coop_id)
        ->where(function ($q){ 
            $q->where('loans.loan_availability', "Always")
            ->orWhere(function ($qq){ 
                $qq->where('loans.loan_availability', "Seasonal")  
                ->where('loan_season_start', '>=', Carbon::now()->month)
                ->where('loan_season_end', '<=', Carbon::now()->month)
                ->where('loan_season_status', 1);
            });
        })
        ->where('loans.loan_status', "1")
        ->get()->toArray();
```

I'm getting this output:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 2
        [coop_id] => 1
        [loan_id] => 3
        [loan_name] => Loan 1
        [loan_desc] => Loan 1 Description
        [loan_maxamount] => 500000
        [loan_availability] => Always
        [loan_status] => 1
        [created_at] => 2017-02-26 17:43:08
        [updated_at] => 2017-02-26 17:43:08
        [loan_season_start] => 2
        [loan_season_end] => 6
        [loan_season_status] => 1
    )
)
```

My expected output is like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [id] => 1
        [coop_id] => 1
        [loan_id] => 3
        [loan_name] => Loan 1
        [loan_desc] => Loan 1 Description
        [loan_maxamount] => 500000
        [loan_availability] => Always
        [loan_status] => 1
        [created_at] => 2017-02-26 17:43:08
        [updated_at] => 2017-02-26 17:43:08
        [loan_season_status] => 1
    )
   [1] => Array(
        [id] => 2
        [coop_id] => 1
        [loan_id] => 4
        [loan_name] => Loan 2
        [loan_desc] => Loan 2 Description
        [loan_maxamount] => 200000
        [loan_availability] => Seasonal
        [loan_season_start] => 2
        [loan_season_end] => 6
        [loan_status] => 1
        [created_at] => 2017-02-26 17:43:08
        [updated_at] => 2017-02-26 17:43:08
        [loan_season_status] => 1
    )
)
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours but I still can't get the query right. Can somebody help? I'm very new to nested queries. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now. Seems like I've been making simple queries complicated. I created different queries for each condition and joined them into one instead. Thanks.